# FTP proxy with SSL support

Tags: ssl, proxy, ftp, lxc

I have a bunch of LXC containers with vsftpd daemon installed on each. I would like to forward/proxy traffic from dom0 server port 21 to particular containers based on ftp user name e.g. **user@domain.com** or domain part to be more precise.

I tried to use *ftp-proxy* and it works perfectly but no SSL support. *Frox* has SSL support but only between proxy and ftpd server.

I found that *squid* can do FTP and SSL but I have never done anything with *squid* and I cannot tell if it's suitable. Maybe you could provide me with information in that matter or give any other idea?

Eventually I will end up with multiple iptables DNAT's pointing directly to containers' *vsftpd* daemon but common port 21 would look great.

Answer (score 1):

You might look into using the mod_proxy module for proftpd; it can do FTPS on the frontend and backend, and do per-user routing.  See [proftpd-mod_proxy](https://github.com/Castaglia/proftpd-mod_proxy)

Full disclaimer: I'm the author/developer of `proftpd` and `mod_proxy`.